# active inactive links in ul accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, accordion

I am trying to get the active and inactive links working correctly in my accordion ul list.

The main menu is highlighted correctly but once I'll click some other link either in the menu or submenu that link doesn't get highlighted. I tried with `:active` and `:selected` but none of them don't work. I created a fiddle for that here: http://jsfiddle.net/laziale/zM2Lw/1/

Comment: Not sure I understand what you're trying to achieve here.  The `:active` selector applies CSS rules after the mouse button has been pressed and before it has been released.  On the website itself, there is no such effect.  I'm using Google Chrome, lastest version.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want the text to appear as a different color when the mouse rolls over the text?  If so, try editing line 803 of styles.css to add the new font color (for example, `color: yellow;`) then adding a new selector:
   `.arrowsidemenu div.unselected a:hover{color:yellow}`

Comment: I want the text to appear as a different color when user clicks on that link.

Comment: Ah.  Then instead of `a:hover`, you want `a:visited`

Answer (score 0):

`a:active {color: #123456}` is what you're looking for if you want the link to change to a certain color as it's clicked. `a:visited` will change the color of the link for users who have already been to whatever page the link leads to.

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp

**EDIT**

Line 871 in your CSS you have `.arrowsidemenu ul li a:hover{ color:Aqua; }`

Add a new class after that for `.arrowsidemenu ul li a:active { color: purple; }`

It will work!

Comment: a:active doesn't want to work, hwoever a:hover works. Is there anything else I am missing out?